# Unwanted WiFi proxy issue

Tags: wi-fi, networking, nexus-7, proxy

I have a Nexus 7 Android tablet.

When I connect to my WiFi at home it keeps automatically adding a proxy on `localhost:3128` to the connection. When I remove the proxy it works for a few hours and then I see the proxy is back.

I removed the WiFi connection and set it up again and I still experience this issue. I don't experience anything similar on my other devices like my Android phone.

Does anyone know how I can figure out what is causing this or how I can fix it (I don't want to do a factory reset)?

Comment: 3128 is the TCP port usually used by cntlm, a ntlm authentication proxy. Does it sound familiar to you?

Comment: @DrNoone, No, it doesn't. I have seen that some desktop software use 3128 as the default proxy port on localhost.

Comment: Does this happen only at your home or also when you connect to other networks, e.g. at a friends house?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a known "feature" if you use Kaspersky Internet Security:

http://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?s=8ffe1c0b8684d5bd3d1353f0d074f528&showtopic=260035

However, as you can see in the link above, it comes with a few issues. Disabling the 'web protection' component seems to do the trick.

Comment: I forgot to mention it does not work in their latest incarnation.